# Moving Files with Batch with XML Data

Tags: batch-file, movefile

I have files that I need to move from an specific directory on schedule.

The files need to move in a folder withing that directory that has all the information separated by the metadata. I have a working Batch that I can run manually, but unable to make it work with scheduler.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%f IN (*.xml) DO (

 (SET destdir=)
 (SET checker=**mydata**)
 (SET fileName=%%f)

 FOR /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%i IN (
   'find "<**mydata**>" ^<"%%f"'
   ) DO SET destdir=%%i

 IF NOT DEFINED destdir (
     FOR /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%i IN (
       'find "<**mydata**>" ^<"%%f"'
       ) DO SET destdir=%%i
       IF DEFINED destdir (
            IF !destdir! == !checker! (
            
                FOR /f "tokens=4 delims=<>" %%i IN (
                   'find "</**mydata**>" ^<"%%f"'
                   ) DO SET destdir=%%i
                )
            )
        )
    CALL :moveme %%f
    )
)
GOTO :eof

:moveme
set directoryUp=%destdir: =%
set mydate=%date:~4%
set mytime=%time::=%
set mytimestamp=!mydate:/=!!mytime:.=!

MD "ArchivedByOOID\%directoryUp%" 2>NUL

IF EXIST "%~dp0ArchivedBy**MyData**\%directoryUp%\%fileName%" (
        MOVE "%fileName%" "%~dp0ArchivedBy**MyData**\%directoryUp%\%mytimestamp%_%fileName%"
) else (
        MOVE "%fileName%" "%~dp0ArchivedBy**MyData**\%directoryUp%" )
GOTO :eof
```

Comment: I have no way of testing this, but a very common mistake that beginners make is not realizing that the Task Scheduler starts the script in the `C:\Windows\System32` directory and so they need to throw a `cd /d "%~dp0"` at the start of the script to begin in the correct location. I also see parentheses around your first three `set` statements that should absolutely be breaking things in a regular execution of the script.

Comment: Is there a way I can define the actual path of the folder:

`FOR %%f IN (DIRECTORY/FOLDERPATH)`

Comment: NVM, I just answer my own question.

Updated `FOR %%f IN ("C:\MYDIRECTORY\*.xml")`

Answer (score 0):

Modified the following to have the directly specified. This allowed BATCH to run the directory needed.

`FOR %%f IN (*.xml)`

to

`FOR %%f IN ("C:\MYDIRECTORY\*.xml")`